# How to get properties of a selected file from a JFileChooser

Tags: java, textfield, jfilechooser

I have an FXML controller class with a textfield that I want populated with various file properties of a file a user selects via a FileChooser.

The controller looks like:

```
@FXML
TextField documentName;

File file;

public void attachNewDocFileChooser() {
    file = new MyFileChooser().chooser();
    if (file != null) {
        documentName.setText(file.getName());
    } else {
        documentName.setText("No file selected");
    }
}
```

The FileChooser is created in a different class `MyFileChooser`:

```
@FXML
public File chooser() {
    File file = null;
    final JFileChooser fileDialog = new JFileChooser();

    int returnVal = fileDialog.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        file = fileDialog.getSelectedFile();
    }
    return file;
}
```

I can't get the textfield `documentName` populated with the name of the file selected.

I'll be very grateful for any help at making this work. Thank you all in advance.

Update:
I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I also forgot to mention that `chooser()` is linked to a Label so that `onMouseClicked="#chooser"`.

Comment: Why not use JavaFX [FileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) instead of the swing JFileChooser?

Comment: Hi @JoopEggen Eggen. I wind up the same. The only difference is that I'll be using a [FileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html), but still the same problem. I don't really mind what I'll be using, FileChooser or the swing JFileChooser, I just want to `documentName.setText(file.getName());` from the controller with the FileChooser being retrieved from another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only NullPointerException could be for `documentName` still being null. That is, that the `@FXML`  did not work. Check the line number of the exception to see whether that is the case. And then go looking into the .fxml file you loaded.

```
@FXML(name="documentName")
public TextField documentName;
```